# Find a complete sufficient statistic,

Tags: self-study, estimation, inference, sufficient-statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be iid observations.Find a complete sufficient statistics for

i)$f(x|\theta)=\frac{\theta}{(1+x)^{1+\theta}}I_{[0\infty)}(x), \theta>0$

What I did
$$\frac{\theta}{(1+x)^{1+\theta}}=\theta (1+x)^{-(1+\theta)}=\theta e^{log(1+x)^{-(1+\theta)}}=\theta e^{-(1+\theta)log(1+x)}$$
$$f_n(x|\theta)=\theta^n e^{-(1+\theta)\sum log(1+x)}$$ then $T(x)=\sum log(1+X)$ is a sufficient statistics, but in general as I check if the statistic is complete?

Can anyone give me a brief explanation of the complete statistical theorem on exponential family,that theorem http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~elkan/291winter2005/lect08.pdf, says that the parameter space contains an open set $\mathbb{R}^k$. But in an exercise of Casella, he applies this theorem when the parameter is set in the range $0\leq \theta \leq 1$

Comment: Same question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176471/complete-sufficient-statistic-exercise?rq=1.

Comment: @user72621 can you specifically mention which question in Casella?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll sketch out an approach but I'll leave the details up to you.

You can show that $\log(1 + X) \sim \Gamma(1, \theta^{-1})$. Use this to find the distribution of your sufficient statistic.

Then you need to suppose that $E(g(T)) = 0$ for an arbitrary function $g$, i.e.
$$
\int \limits_0^\infty g(t) f_T(t)dt = 0
$$

where I'm ignoring parameters. You'll need to fill those in appropriately.

Use this to make a statement about $g$ so that you can conclude that $P(g(T) = 0) = 1$ for all $\theta \in \Theta$.

Edit:
Because you know the exponential family result, I'll go through this proof in more detail.

Let $Y = \log(1+X)$. Note that this is 1-1. The inverse of the transformation is $X = \exp(Y) - 1$ so the Jacobian is $e^Y$. Putting this together we have
$$
f_Y(y|\theta) = f_X(e^y - 1|\theta) \times e^y
$$
$$
= \frac{\theta e^y}{(1 + e^y - 1)^{\theta + 1}} \times I(0 < y < \infty)
$$
$$
= \theta e^{-\theta y} =_d \Gamma(1, \theta^{-1})
$$
where I'm dropping the indicator because the support is independent of $\theta$ so it's not too important.

This means that $T \sim \Gamma(n, \theta^{-1})$ and therefore
$$
E(g(T)) = \int \limits_0^\infty g(t) t^n e^{-\theta t} \frac{\theta^n}{\Gamma(n)} dt =_{set} 0
$$

$$
\implies \int \limits_0^\infty g(t) t^n e^{-\theta t} dt = 0.
$$

Because $\forall t > 0$ and $\theta > 0$ $t^n e^{-\theta t} > 0$, it must be that $g(t) = 0$ almost surely (you could do this a lot more rigorously).

Comment: I've been trying here, but I could not show that $log(1+X)~Gamma(1,\theta^{-1})$

Comment: Use the Jacobian theorem. Let $Y = \log(1+X)$, solve for $X$, find the Jacobian, plug everything in, and you should recognize the resulting density.

Comment: Do you know about a theorem that says if a function belongs to the exponential family and the parameter space is an open range that ensures complete statistics of existence?

Comment: I am familiar with the result. Is this an exponential family? If so, you're done.

Comment: Yes is exponential family, only that there is a restriction on the parametric space, but I can not remember how

Comment: [Completeness](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~elkan/291winter2005/lect08.pdf). Maybe I understand this wrong, but here he says that the parameter space $\Theta$ contains an open set in $R^k$, but an exercise in my book he used this theorem when $0\leq \theta \leq 1$

Comment: This means that $\Theta$ *contains* an open set, i.e. has a non-empty interior (e.g. we can't have $\Theta = \{0, 1, 2\}$). It does not mean that $\Theta$ has to be an open set itself, although it certainly can be.

Comment: From the final integral being zero, how do we get $g(t) = 0$ a.s.?  Couldn't $g(t)$ be + and - over different parts of its domain?

Comment: @ShangZhang yeah, good question, I wasn’t very clear there. It’s because the integral equation holds for _all_ $\theta$ with just this one $g$ so there isn’t any wiggle room to be anything but zero. I’m traveling with limited internet for the next several days but I’ll update when I can

Comment: You are right.  I see that now.  $g(t) t^n$ is the inverse Laplace transformation.

Comment: @ShangZhang yeah that’s the clearest way I can think of to see it