# complete sufficient statistic exercise

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, exponential-family, sufficient-statistics, point-estimation

I have to find complete sufficient statistic of the following pdf

$$f(x|\theta)=\frac{\theta}{(1+x)^{(1+\theta)}},\quad 0<x<\infty,\theta>0.$$

#### My Attempt:

The joint density

$$f(\mathbf x|\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\theta}{(1+x_i)^{(1+\theta)}}$$

$$=\theta^n\prod_{i=1}^{n}\exp[-(1+\theta)\log(1+x_i)]$$
$$=\theta^n\exp[-(1+\theta)\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(1+x_i)]$$

So, $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(1+x_i)$ is complete sufficient.

But it seems to me I am wrong. What will be the correct answer ?

Comment: What is wrong with this derivation? The likelihood factorises through this sufficient statistic and this is a regular exponential family.

Answer (score 4):

Your derivation is correct.  You have a regular exponential family, so the factorization theorem gives $\sum_i \log (1+x_i)$ is sufficient, and complete since it is a regular exponential family.

Comment: Why does regular exponential family imply that the statistic is complete? Can you link to a proof of this claim?

Comment: See my answer here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/391296/poisson-distribution-and-completeness-what-happens-when-one-point-removed-from/395138#395138